# Route resolve execution order and dependency

Tags: angularjs, angularfire, angular-routing

This is a resolve I have:

```
.when('/chat', {
    templateUrl: 'chat.html',
    controller: 'ChatController',
    resolve: {
        currentUser: ['Auth', function (Auth) {
            return Auth.$requireSignIn(true);
        }],
        messages: ['$firebaseArray', function ($firebaseArray) {
            return $firebaseArray(firebase.database().ref('messages')).$loaded();
        }],
        userList: ['$firebaseArray', function ($firebaseArray) {
            return $firebaseArray(firebase.database().ref('online')).$loaded();
        }]
    }
})
```

`messages` and `userList` requires authentication, so how can I get `messages` and `userList` resolved only if `currentUser` resolves?

Comment: i think you have to use promises ... and then check if you have auth token and inject it in the header of request

Comment: Not sure if this is applicable in your case, but I would create abstract parent state that will do auth, i.e. state authenticated. And then extend all states from it.
Another way is to chain promises, but this one I cant provide from head since dont know angularfire well)